# How to make "render_template" functional?

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

In my very simle Flask app "rendare_template" is not working. What do I need to set, code or remove from my code?

```
main.py

import requests
from flask import (Blueprint, render_template, abort)
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
from flask import Flask
import simple_page
from simple_page import simple_page

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(simple_page)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(debug=True)

simple_page.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

simple_page = Blueprint('simple_page', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@simple_page.route('/', defaults={'page': 'index'})
@simple_page.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    try:
        return render_template('pages/%s.html' % page)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

When I run the code, I am getting:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: @johnny243 I am trying to access http://127.0.0.1:5000/index where in my template folder I have a external index.html file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Flask will look for templates in the `templates` folder.

```
...
return render_template('pages/%s.html' % page)
```

You should create a `pages` folder inside `templates` folder and move your templates there.

So when you access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index`, your code will look for `index.html` inside `templates/pages`

See [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) for more information.

Comment: If you read the article you sent me, you will see that there is not a single sentence related to PAGES folder, thank you Sir.

Comment: There is no reference to the `pages` folder on the docs, but this is something you added on your code. It is up to you and it's valid if you want to organize your project that way.

Comment: I have a similar application, main application where I get the same error and I don't have a pages folder, nevermind, thank you anyway Sir.